# Compiling Linux assembler on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, x86

```
    .string "Hello\n"
    .globl main
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl $hello
    call puts
    movl $0, %eax
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

This code works on 32bit Linux. How can I run this on Windows?

```
gcc hello.s
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a Windows version of an x86 assembler. The GNU Assembler is available on Windows through the [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) project. This is the same assembler you are using on Linux.

Comment: undefined reference to puts, and WinMain@16 using mingw 4.8.1 x86

Comment: @JKS: I forget, but Windows name mangling might put an `_` in front of C names.  In that case, you'd need to `call _puts`.  Aside from that, your code appears portable between the Linux and Windows 32bit ABIs.  (Both use a stack-args calling convention).